# CDT time conversion to salesforce dateime field format

Tags: apex, datetime, parsing

I have been stuck in a problem actually i am trying to covert a datetime format in salesforce date time field format

The datetime format which i am getting is `2020-09-13 10:37 CDT`
I tried removing CDT from the end like this but it is not working

```
String startDate = String.valueOf(assetActivity.get('actstart')
                .getValue()).removeEnd('CDT');
            
            Datetime dt = datetime.parse(startDate);
            system.debug('dt'+dt);
            ts.Start_Time__c = dt;
```

It is always throwing error of invalid date/time please help me out
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note the time needs to be transformed to GMT based on the timezone:

```
String[] dateTimeSplit = String.valueOf(assetActivity.get('actstart')
                .getValue()).split(' ');
String[] dateSplit = dateTimeSplit[0].split('-');
String[] timeSplit = dateTimeSplit[1].split(':'); //you will have to write a function that converts the time to GMT based on the dateTimeSplit[2] literal
Datetime dt = DateTime.newInstanceGmt( Integer.valueOf(dateSplit[0]), Integer.valueOf(dateSplit[1]), Integer.valueOf(dateSplit[2]), Integer.valueOf(timeSplit[0]), Integer.valueOf(timeSplit[1]), 0);
system.debug('dt'+dt);
ts.Start_Time__c = dt;
```

[See DateTime newInstanceGmt method](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm)

Comment: Thanks for your response but it didn't work for me i tried this code 
String[] dateTimeSplit = String.valueOf(assetActivity.get('actstart')
                                                        .getValue()).split(' ');
                system.debug('dateTimeSplit'+dateTimeSplit);
                Datetime dt = datetime.parse(dateTimeSplit[0] + 'T' + dateTimeSplit[1]);
                system.debug('dt'+dt);
                ts.Start_Time__c = dt;
It is giving this error now Invalid date/time: 2020-09-15T05:42

Comment: That will not work because you need to append the timezone difference to GMT. For CDT, it is '-05:00'. If your times will come in GMT time, then you have to append a 'Z'

Comment: If you see your ternary operator it will always return '-5:00' and that is not a datetime format

Comment: I missed a parenthesis when calculating the trailing timezone adjustment, but just realized timezone literals do not work with parse method. Editing my original response..

Comment: Thanks for response but now i am getting this error
Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void valueOf(String, Integer) from the type Integer

Comment: You may have introduced an error when copying the function (note that I added the last 0 param for seconds). Try copying it as is now

Comment: I am using this code String[] dateTimeSplit = String.valueOf('2020-09-13 13:18 CDT').split(' ');
String[] dateSplit = dateTimeSplit[0].split('-');
                String[] timeSplit = dateTimeSplit[1].split(':'); 
                system.debug('dateSplit '+dateSplit +':::'+timeSplit);
                Datetime dt = DateTime.newInstanceGmt(Integer.valueOf(dateSplit[0]), Integer.valueOf(dateSplit[1]), Integer.valueOf(dateSplit[2]), Integer.valueOf(timeSplit[0]), Integer.valueOf(timeSplit[1],0));
                system.debug('dt'+dt);

Comment: Still it is throwing this error Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void valueOf(String, Integer) from the type Integer don't know why it is throwing this error

Comment: That is not what I posted, your last parentheses are wrong: change ,0)) for ),0)

Comment: Ohh sorry my bad i missed that Now it has worked like a charm Thank you very much

Comment: I am glad you got this. Please note that you do need to write that function to convert the time to GMT before passing the hh and mm params to the newInstanceGMT otherwise you'll get it wrong

Comment: Sure Thanks for your help